# Gitosis install issues

Tags: git, gitosis

I've installed gitosis using the instructions on the main site  (http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way). Searching the net it seems pretty standard install method. However I seem to be getting the following error when trying to clone gitosis-admin.

> git clone git@192.168.1.20:gitosis-admin.git
>       fatal: 'gitosis-admin.git' does not appear to be a git repository
>       fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be? I'm running gitosis with
Arch Linux
Python 2.6.3
Git 1.6.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was with .ssh/authorized_keys, I had two entries for my client the first was the one I added to allow passwordless login. The second was the entry auto generated by gitosis. Deleting the first of these solved my issue.